How to read a raw disk without locking/dismounting the volume, using Win32 API?
This StackOverflow question has an answer that requires the volume to be locked/dismounted, but it seems this is not necessarily required. When I use the hex editor HxD (Tools > Open disk) to open a volume (logical disks) or a physical disk, I can open C: and even the SSD it is in seamlessly. I can keep using the C drive without problems, and HxD updates its content.
Also, when I use MSVC, with fopen("\\\\.\\D:", "rb") and fgetc(), I am able to read the first byte of the raw disk/volume D:. This also happens with MinGW, which I think links to MSVC's library.
So, how can I do this using the Win32 API? Or is MSVC doing sinister things that are not normally done by the Win32 API?

Try using DefineDosDevice. It can map a physical device to a logical device.  DosDevice's are symbolic links in the NT Object Manager database pointing to the underlying devices. Then use createfile to access the disk.

@Torrecto-MSFT DefineDosDevice here absolute not need at all

MSVC doing ))) msvc nothing doing at all. this is funny. it is simply integrated shell for compile, link and debug

can I do this using the Win32 API? in what problem create file via CreateFileW or NtOpenFile and read from it ?

You could peer into HxD (my favorite on Windows) with a tool like depends (dependencywalker.com) and see what API they import. The testrec utility is quite powerful, low level and open source. You might find what you are looking for in it.

@RbMm, I tried CreateFile("\\\\.\\D:", ...) and ReadFile(), but it complained saying "Parameter is invalid". I was really sure it was gonna work seeing MinGW and MSVC.

How possible say, which parameter is incorrect, when you not show your actual code. And of course mingw or msvc here absolute unrelated at all

@RbMm, I have tried this. The output was "Read: the parameter is incorrect". Also, I mentioned MinGW because when I compiled it and checked its output .exe (using dumpbin), it used msvcrt.dll for functions like fopen(). But it is unrelated to the question.

of course the parameter is incorrect, because you use FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING. in this case size and offset of data must be multiple sector size. and you try read 2 bytes. and already in 3 time repeat - mingw, msvc, etc - here unrelated and can not be related

@RbMm, after I replaced FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING for 0, it still returned the same error, But! Then I changed the number of bytes to be read to 512, and it worked! This is kinda weird. Thank you a lot for this information! -- You're kind of a magician! Do you any documentation or something that states it, so I could look further?

For disk devices the no buffering implicitly set always. So you really always need multiple sector size and offset. Also buffer aligned on device align requires, but this usually not more 4 bytes

@Schilive Here is the doc you want: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/fileio/file-buffering#alignment-and-file-access-requirements

@RbMm, thank you. I think you could make an answer with the comments.

@Schilive I can make a community for Mr Rbmm. Just accept it and it won't add reputation for me.

@Torrecto-MSFT, thank you a lot. I edited a little. Do you think it is still good?

@Schilive Excellent.

As @RbMm said, CreateFile("\\\\.\\D:", ...) can make it just as fopen("\\\\.\\D:", "rb"). This is nothing related to MinGW and MSVC.
When using the flag FILE_FLAG_NO_BUFFERING, which is implicit for devices, the size and offset of data must be a multiple of the sector size. For example,
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define SECTOR_SIZE 512

int main()
{
        HANDLE hFile;
        unsigned char buf[SECTOR_SIZE];
        DWORD rd;
        hFile = CreateFile(
                "\\\\.\\D:", 
                /* "GENERIC_WRITE" for writing access. */
                GENERIC_READ,
                /* Necessary to allow other programs to read and write to the
                 * device.
                 */
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,
                OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL
        );
        if (hFile == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Cuuld not open file: %lu\n", GetLastError());
                return 1;
        }

        if (ReadFile(hFile, buf, SECTOR_SIZE, &rd, NULL) == FALSE) {
                fprintf(stderr, "Could not read file: %lu\n", GetLastError());
                CloseHandle(hFile);
                return 1;
        }
        for (size_t i = 0; i < SECTOR_SIZE; i++)
                printf("%X ", buf[i]);

        CloseHandle(hFile);
        return 0;
}

